# C - sockets - epoll. What with slow clients?

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

### Context

Debian64bits.

Thought I understood socket implications but not.

Worried about the management of slow clients.

Read and fiddled with that code [epoll edge triggered](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/epoll-example.c)

Imagine two clients:
A: very slow network
B: very fast network.

### Question

In edge triggered mode what would happen when we start reading from A and then B also sends some datas to read while we are in the read loop for A?

Will B have to wait for us to read all the datas coming from A?

Or should we create a buffer (not in the example given) to store A datas and concatenate those until the message is complete and return immediately?

Or is that buffer already managed by epoll?

The underlying is not clear to me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the network is slow, the reading part will stop whenever it has read all data that has reached the server so far.

There is a bug (or at least a portability issue) in it though. The code only checks for `EAGAIN` when reading data. It should also check for `EWOULDBLOCK`, since some platforms return that error code when all data has been read.

**Edit:**

> Ok, so if i want to put the incoming datas into a database, how could i manage it? Will i be able to read the whole datas?

If you get an incomplete message you would need to store it until the entire message has been received. I would `malloc` a `char*` for each incoming connection with a message fragment.

When a message is complete, you can process it, store it in the database or whatever you desire.

Note that the beginning of the next message may already be available, so you can't stop reading until you get `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`.

Another way to treat the problem is to create a separate thread for each connection. 
Which approcah is best? Well, that would depend on the application (number of simultaneous users etc).

Comment: Ok, so if i want to put the incoming datas into a database, how could i manage it? Will i be able to read the whole datas?

Comment: Thanks! So i have to create a mean to manage all the malloc'd arrays (array of pointers to malloc) and call them accordingly if nothing else seems to be to read and flush that to the db, right?

Comment: I would create a separate thread to write to the database, and send messages to it via a queue. But that depends on your requirements. You could write to the database using the same thread whenever you get a complete message, but that would slow down the response time since the server would have to wait for the database call to  complete.